# Disallow windowed mode on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

We are about to create Windows Phone Cordova app for one particular model of tablet and for landscape position of screen. Our concern is that Windows Phone allows user to display several apps side by side. Can we somehow disallow this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. Try This.

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

This should be in App.Xaml on OnLaunched